# c# How to use variable across forms

Tags: c#

Requirement: Capture the user ID from `form1` and use it across other Forms.

Structure:

- Form1 - Login Form (user input Login ID and Password)
- Form2 - Selection Form (user choose the other forms from here as they
  wish)
- Form3,4...  - are the Data input forms which then imports the entry
  to Database as they finish and press save.

**Form1 code:**

```
namespace xxxxx
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

      {

       //Establish Conection

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MaximizeBox = false;
        }



private void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            //Opening Connection - checking User input match with DB
            // Once matched open Form2

                string userName = txt_Username.Text;
                Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                f2.ShowMe = userName;
                f2.Show();
                this.Hide();
           //closing Connection

        }
```

**Form2 Code:**

```
namespace xxxxx
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
       public string ShowMe { get; set; }

       public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MaximizeBox = false;

        }

 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            passName.Text = ShowMe;
        }
```

It works fine as it gets the User ID and display in `form2` label. However when I do the same thing for Form3 it doesn't work.

**FORM2 code continue:**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string myVal = passName.Text;
            Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            f3.ShowMe = myVal;
            f3.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

**FORM3 Code:**

```
namespace xxxxxxx
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public string ShowMe { get; set; }


        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MaximizeBox = false;

        }

        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UName.Text = ShowMe;
        }
```

I am not sure why it is not displaying User ID on to form 3 label as i used the same method for FORM 2.

any help will be really appreciated.
-Viku

Comment: I suggest that you should use Mediator design pattern. Search for it description on Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can declare variable using `static` keyword which means there is only one copy of the static member.

You can delcare it in *Form1* class or another *separate class*.
For example, you have delcare it in another *separate class* called `ConstValue` as

> public static string ShowMe {get;set;}

So, set the value of the `username` (in your context) like this directly without creating an instance of the class from **Form1**

> ConstValue.ShowMe=txt_Username.Text;

And in order to get the value; let's assume you have `label1` *control* in **Form4**. So, in *Form4* coding do this:

> label.Text=ConstValue.ShowMe;

Hope you understand and it helps easily.

Comment: I created public class called "ConstValue" in program class and declare ShowMe as public static string ShowMe {get; set;}       then in FORM1 I assign value as   Program.ConstValue.ShowMe = txt_Username.Text; under FORM1 class. when i accessed the value in FROM2  as passName.Text = Program.ConstValue.ShowMe;    under Form2 class, running the program shows blank value.  Please advice.

Comment: Strange enough: when i assign value as "Hello" instead  txt_Username.Text  .... it is picking up. Please advise what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: It is working properly now. I just assigned the value in initialising form which of course was not going to work. thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Viku: sorry to reply late. I have gone through the same problem in the past. I know how it feels to get stuck and frustated while coding. It's my pleasure to share knowledge what i know.  It helped u and that's good.

Answer (score 4):

The most simple solution is to define `public static` object in `Program` class. It is accessible from all forms.

Answer (score 0):

On form 1 calling form 2, you are setting "ShowMe" value to

```
string userName = txt_Username.Text;
```

On form 1 calling form 3, you are setting "ShowMe" value to

```
string myVal = passName.Text;
```

Was that intended??  Or did you mean to also have form 3 use the "txt_Username.Text" value.

Additionally, by having the public string at the form, you are open to have that value being set from anywhere by possible accident.  You might consider adding a parameter to your other forms vs the public and passing the string in you want to show.  Something like...

```
public Form2(string showMeFromFirstForm )
{
   InitializeComponent();
   MaximizeBox = false;
   passName.Text = showMeFromFirstForm;
}
```

and in your first form button, you could simplify to

```
private void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form2 f2 = new Form2( txt_Username.Text );
   f2.Show();
   this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: FORM 1 is only calling FORM2 .. FORM 2 is calling FORM 3. my aim is to have the user ID in FORM 2 label as well as FORM 3 label.

Comment: @Viku, revised answer to show alternate option for your approach... maybe that will help being more explicit in WHAT you are passing to the second and similarly third forms...